# Intersection of Ideals in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is clear that $I = \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle $ is an ideal.
I am trying to prove that $a_1b_1 - a_2b_2 \in I \ \forall  \ a_1b_1,a_2b_2 \in I $

It seems so easy but I am stuck. Thanks

Comment: what is your definition of an ideal?

Comment: Any ideal is closed under multiplication and sum.

Comment: than use that! Is $a_1b_1$ in $I$ ? and what about $a_2b_2$

Comment: sorry sorry, it was a typo

Comment: @Sigur: I think that it is closed under multiplication and substraction...

Comment: @mookid, it is the same since $a-b=a+(-b)$.

Comment: "closed under multiplication and sum" means that $\Bbb N$ is an ideal!

Comment: Note that elements of $\,(a)\cap (b)\,$ need not be of the form $\,a_1 b_1\,$ for $\,a_1\in (a),\,\ b_1\in (b),\,$ e.g. $\,12\in (4)\cap(6)\subset \Bbb Z\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Note that by assumption $a_1b_1, a_2b_2 \in \langle a \rangle$, since $\langle a \rangle \supseteq I$. Multiplying by $-1$, we find that $(-1)a_2b_2 \in \langle a \rangle$, using the property that ideals absorb multiplication. Since $\langle a \rangle$ is an ideal, then it is closed under addition, so $a_1b_1 + (-1)a_2b_2 = a_1b_1- a_2b_2 \in \langle a \rangle$. Similarly, $a_1b_1 - a_2b_2 \in \langle b \rangle$. So $a_1b_1 - a_2b_2 \in \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle$.

Comment: Nice! But we don't know if the OP is using the fact that $I$ is already an ideal.

Comment: I don't think I used that fact; I just used the fact that $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$ are ideals. Assuming, of course, that the notation $\langle x \rangle$ means the ideal generated by $x$.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. You well wrote.

Comment: and how do you know that $(-1)\in I$?

Comment: It need not be in $I$, it only need be in the ring. For any ideal $J$ of a ring $R$, $ra \in J$ for any $r \in R$ and $a \in J$. Although fair point, I guess I assumed the ring in question has a $1$.

Comment: Why do you assume $\,a_i \in (a)\,$ and $\,b_i \in (b)\,?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Whoops! Edited.

Comment: See my comment to the question.